# hdfs reformat name node failed by error Unable to check if JNs are ready for formatting

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, apache-zookeeper, namenode

I want to start fresh hdfs cluster, I start zookeeper and yarn with command :
`./zkServer.sh start && start-yarn.sh`
after above command I started journalnode on each 5 node with command:
`hdfs --daemon start journalnode`

now, before starting namenodes (2 node) i should format namenode :
`hdfs namenode -format`

but this command cause many INFO like:

```
INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: bgdata-c11/192.168.30.171:8485. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

and finally this error:

```
ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumException: Unable to check if JNs are ready for formatting. 2 exceptions thrown:
192.168.30.173:8485: Call From bgdata-c11/192.168.30.171 to bgdata-c13:8485 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
192.168.30.171:8485: Call From bgdata-c11/192.168.30.171 to bgdata-c11:8485 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

can any one help me please!

what i want is to format namenode while journalnodes are active for the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem, It is coming from zookeeper, there is a file that I created for zookeeper to store it's data (node's ID)... I don't understand why it's causing a problem but when I tried to recreate it, the problem disappeared

it works but I do not understand the reason. Can any one explain in more detail please?

Answer (score 0):

In `hdfs-site.xml` file there is a property called : `dfs.journalnode.edits.dir`

You need the delete this folder content in every journal node

Be careful when formatting your cluster (your data will be deleted)